# I'm attempting to make it so animals will go to the nearest entity they feed on

Tags: python, pygame

Im attempting to get my program to determine the distance between multiple different sprites and go for the closest one but it doesn't do this instead it goes for a fixed one and all of them stop moving after one of them has eaten the sprite instead they should go for the new closest one if they are still hungry.

```
if len(preys) > 0:
            for wolf in Wolf_group:
                for rabbits in Rabbit_group:
                    preysX,preysY=wolf.findClosestPrey(self,rabbit.x,rabbit.y)
                    movementx, movementy = Track(wolf.x, preysX, wolf.y, preysY)#how the predators move
                    wolf.move(movementx,movementy)#movementx, #movementy)
```

the function

```
 def findClosestPrey(self,preyX,preyY):
        tempdist=math.sqrt((self.x-preyX)**2 + (self.y-preyX)**2)
        if tempDist<dist:
            xpos=preyX
            ypos=preyX

        return xpos, ypos
```

Im not sure why it does this as it should be fine

full code:

```
#simulates interactions of wild life
import math
import random
import pygame,sys 
import random
import pdb
import time
from pygame.locals  import *

pygame.init()#setsup pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800))#setsup screen size
clock = pygame.time.Clock()#tells program how fast to update
timmer = 1#how long program has gone on for


#colours
grey=(60,60,60)
dark_grey=(20,20,20)
dark_blue=(0,0,160)
black=(0,0,0)



#classes-------------------------------------------------------------------
class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):#main class
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x #min(max(0, self.x), screen_width)
        self.y = x #min(max(0, self.y), screen_height)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.Energy=10
        
        
    def move(self, mx, my):#moves the sprite
        self.x += mx
        self.y += my
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))#sets the image to the position

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):#is the eat function
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)
    
    def checkEnergy(self):#checks the energy of an animal
        EnergyVal=self.energy
        return EnergyVal

    
    def starve(self,sprite):# kills of sprite if energy hits bottom.
        if self.energy<=0:
            sprite.kill()
        else:
            self.energy-=1
            print("starving")
            self.starvetimmer=0

    
    
class Predator(Animal):#class for predators
    def __init__(self,image, x, y):
        super().__init__(image, x, y)
        self.energy=9
        self.starvetimmer=0
        self.dist=1000

    def reproduce(self):
        if self.energy >= 15:
            predator = Predator(self.image,600,600 )#elf.x, self.y)
            all_sprites.add(predator)
            Wolf_group.add(predator)
            self.energy -= 6
            

    def findClosestPrey(self,preyX,preyY):
        tempdist=math.sqrt((self.x-preyX)**2 + (self.y-preyY)**2)
        if tempdist<self.dist:
            xpos=preyX
            ypos=preyX
    

  
         
class Prey(Animal):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__(image, x, y)
        self.energy=7
        self.starvetimmer=0
        self.dist=10000
        

    def reproduce(self):
        if self.energy >= 10:
            prey = Prey(self.image,self.x-50,self.y+50 )#elf.x, self.y)
            all_sprites.add(prey)
            Rabbit_group.add(prey)
            self.energy -= 6
            
    

        return xpos, ypos
            
        
        


class Carrot(pygame.sprite.Sprite):#food for prey class
    def __init__(self,image,x,y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))

        def carrot_creation():
            randomx=random.randint(0,9)
            randomy=random.randint(0,9)

            randomx=randomx*100
            randomy=randomy*100
            
            carrot=Carrot(carrot_image,(randomx,randomy))
            all_sprites.add(carrot)
            carrot_group.add(carrot)





# Functions--------------------------------------------------------------
def Track(AgressorX,DefenderX,AgressorY,DefenderY):#finds comapres X and Y, tells sprite how to move
    if AgressorX > DefenderX:
        XMovement=-1
    elif AgressorX< DefenderX:
        XMovement=1
    else:
        XMovement=0
        
    if AgressorY > DefenderY:
        YMovement=-1
    elif AgressorY < DefenderY: 
        YMovement=1
    else:
        YMovement=0
    return XMovement, YMovement

def leavingWindow(Xpos, Ypos):#boundry, keeps sprites in the window
    if Xpos<=0:
        return True
    elif Xpos>=950:
        return True   
    if Ypos<=0:
        return True
    elif Ypos>=750:
        return True

def Boundry(Xpos, Ypos):
    Xmovement = min(max(0, Xpos), 950)
    ymovement = min(max(0, Ypos), 750)

    return Xmovement, ymovement

def button(msg,x,y,width,height,inactiveColour,activecolour,action=None):#setup buttons
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()#gets mouses position
    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()#sees if the mouse is clicked

    if x+width> mouse[0] > x and y+height> mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, activecolour,(x,y,width, height))
        if click[0]==1 and action!=None:
            if action=="play":
                main_game()
            elif action=="quit":
                pygame.quit
                quit()
            elif action=="pause":
                paused()
                
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, inactiveColour,(x,y,width,height))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",16)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(width/2)), (y+(height/2)) )
    screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)



    button("pause",450,450,100,50,grey,dark_grey,"play")
    button("Quit",450,550,100,50,grey,dark_grey,"quit")


    
    
def text_objects(text, font):#sets up the text
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def paused():

    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((1000/2),(800/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    

    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        #gameDisplay.fill(white)
        

        button("Continue",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,unpause)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)  


#classes and sprites--------------------------------------------------------

#setup sprite groups

prey_image = pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
predator_image=pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
carrot_image=pygame.image.load("carrot.png")

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

carrot_group = pygame.sprite.Group()


Wolf_group= pygame.sprite.Group()
Wolf_group.add(Predator(predator_image,600,600))

Rabbit_group= pygame.sprite.Group()


#sets up multiple rabbits and carrots at start
for i in range(1, 3):
    prey = Prey(prey_image, 100 * i, 700)
    all_sprites.add(prey)
    Rabbit_group.add(prey)

for i in range(0,3):#makes arndom carrots
    randomx=random.randint(0,9)
    randomy=random.randint(0,9)

    randomx=randomx*100
    randomy=randomy*100
    
    carrot=Carrot(carrot_image,randomx,randomy)
    all_sprites.add(carrot)
    carrot_group.add(carrot)

all_sprites.add(carrot_group)
all_sprites.add(Wolf_group)
all_sprites.add(Rabbit_group)


#start of program
def main_game():
    timmer = 1
    running=True
    while running:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                running=False
        #buttons
        #button("pause",650,30,100,50,grey,dark_grey,"play")
        #button("Quit",750,30,100,50,grey,dark_grey,"quit")

        carrots = carrot_group.sprites()
        preys = Rabbit_group.sprites()
        predators = Wolf_group.sprites()

        if len(preys) > 0:
            for wolf in Wolf_group:
                for rabbits in Rabbit_group:
                    preysX,preysY=wolf.findClosestPrey(rabbits.x,rabbits.y)
                    movementx, movementy = Track(wolf.x, preysX, wolf.y, preysY)#how the predators move
                    wolf.move(movementx,movementy)#movementx, #movementy)

                Leaving=leavingWindow(wolf.x,wolf.y)#keeps sprites in window
                if Leaving == True:
                    movementx,movementy=Boundry(wolf.x,wolf.y)
                    wolf.x=movementx
                    wolf.y=movementy

        if len(carrots) > 0:#the movement for prey
            for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
                for carrot in carrot_group:
                    
                   
##                  Energyval=rabbit.checkEnergy()
##                  if Energyval>=8:
                    movementx, movementy = Track(rabbit.x, carrot.x, rabbit.y, carrot.y)#how the prey move
                    rabbit.move(movementx, movementy)

                Leaving=leavingWindow(rabbit.x,rabbit.y)#keeps sprites in window
                if Leaving == True:
                    movementx,movementy=Boundry(rabbit.x,rabbit.y)
                    rabbit.x=movementx
                    rabbit.y=movementy
        
        for carrot in carrots:#removes the carrots if they contact a rabbit
            for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
                if rabbit.is_collided_with(carrot):
                    print('works')
                    carrot.kill()
                    rabbit.dist=1000

                    rabbit.energy += 5#increases the rabbits energy 
                    rabbit.reproduce()#reproduces once the
                    
                if rabbit.starvetimmer==120:#starves the animal over time
                    rabbit.starve(rabbit)
                else:
                    rabbit.starvetimmer+=1

        for wolf in Wolf_group:
            for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
                if rabbit.is_collided_with(wolf):
                    print("works 2")
                    wolf.dist=1000
                    rabbit.kill()

                    wolf.energy+=4#increases the rabbits energy 
                    wolf.reproduce()
                    

            if wolf.starvetimmer==160:
                wolf.starve(wolf)
            else:
                wolf.starvetimmer+=1


        
                
            


        screen.fill((0,128,0))#background
        all_sprites.draw(screen)#makes the sprites
        pygame.display.update()#updates screen
        timmer+=1
               
        
    pygame.quit()
    exit()



#main menu setup-----------------------------------------------------


def main_menu():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        screen.fill(dark_blue)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",100)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Wildlife simulator", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((1000/2),(200))
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Start",450,450,100,50,grey,dark_grey,"play")
        button("Quit",450,550,100,50,grey,dark_grey,"quit")

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

play=True

#main loop
while play==True:
    #main_menu()

    main_game()
```

Comment: In `findClosestPrey`, what is `dist` and where is it defined? Also, it's not clear why you need that function, since all it does is return the X and Y you passed in. The surrounding logic also isn't clear; you're not finding the closest prey for each wolf, you're literally telling each wolf in `Wolf_group` to go after every rabbit in `Rabbit_group`. So, if every wolf is told to do the identical thing, they'll all probably go to the position of the very last rabbit in the list. Just like what you're describing. So, it's not clear at all why you've written things that way.

Comment: `foo == True` is redundant and not meaningful. Just write `foo`.

Comment: You seem to have a bug? Are you sure you want to use `preyX` instead of `preyY` in the `findClosestPrey` method?

Comment: there is [pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to)

Comment: @Random how about would I go about changing it to make it so that each wolf goes for a different item

Comment: @Flat_Pancake you probably want each wolf to go to the one rabbit closest to them. Not to every rabbit. But I don't know exactly how you want it to work, it's your program. As far as finding the closest one, for each wolf you'll have to get the distance to each rabbit from each wolf, then pick the rabbit with the smallest distance to that wolf, and move the wolf to that position. As far as how to do all that, that's up to you, it will require a few different changes. We're not going to write the correct, complete version for you but we can answer your questions if you get stuck on anything.

Comment: not expecting to, what you gave ( having a list style thing) was what I was expecting in response so thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code cannot work because the `findClosestPrey` method does not return anything:

> ```py
> def findClosestPrey(self,preyX,preyY):
>    tempdist=math.sqrt((self.x-preyX)**2 + (self.y-preyY)**2)
>    if tempdist<self.dist:
>        xpos=preyX
>        ypos=preyX
> ```

You need to pass a list or group of targets (*Sprites*) to the `findClosestPrey` method. The method finds the target with the closest distance and returns its position. Return the position of the object itself if there are no targets:

```py
class Predator(Animal):
    # [...]

    def getDistanceTo(self, preyX, preyY):
        return math.sqrt((self.x-preyX)**2 + (self.y-preyY)**2)

    def findClosestPrey(self, targets):
        if not targets:
            return self.x, self.y
        
        minDist = 1000000 # very large distance
        for target in targets:
            tempDist = self.getDistanceTo(target.x, target.y)
            if tempDist < minDist:
                targetX = target.x
                targetY = target.y
        return targetX, targetY
```

```py
def main_game():
    # [...]

    while running:
        # [...]

        if len(preys) > 0:
            for wolf in Wolf_group:
                preysX, preysY = wolf.findClosestPrey(Rabbit_group)
                movementx, movementy = Track(wolf.x, preysX, wolf.y, preysY)
                wolf.move(movementx, movementy)

                # [...]
```